# no record shown in dropdown from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried retrieving all table names in mysql using php and place it in a html dropdown (which is (select). I have tried every way possible but still cant figure it out why it does not show anything. Here's my code and please do supply a decent and working answer. If you have or want some additional info just reply and i will update or reply your answer.

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <Select type="text"  style="width:220px; height: 30px;">

        <?php
        $dbname = 'databasename';

        if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')) {
            echo 'Could not connect to mysql';

        }

        $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();

        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo '<select>';
            $tables = $r['databasename'];
            echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
        }


        mysql_free_result($result);
        echo '</select>';

        ?>


    </select>
</div>
```

Please supply a very understandable reply.

Thank you.

Comment: Your DB connection method is incorrect. Visit http://www.php.net/mysql_connect You first need to connect, THEN show an error if there is no connection.

Comment: Use mysqli_query, take your "echo '<select>';" out of the while loop. "$r['databasename'];" should be "$row['databasename'];".

There is a lot more wrong here. What part do you not understand

Comment: I see several oddities in the fetch.  You create `$row` in the while loop, but later attempt to use `$r['databasename']` Then, you need to inspect the array `$row` contains with `var_dump($row)`. It will _not_ have a key `databasename`.

Comment: why is select being echoed in loop?

Comment: Thanks for being so nice about it (sense of sarcasm I can do without) and you can figure it out for yourself. We're not "write it up for me, I'm a sucker for punishment). (Edit: yeah, you deleted your comment and I did see it just in time too).

Comment: (1) move your `<select>` outside/before your loop. (2) change your loop to `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { echo '<option>'.$r[0].'</option>'; }`

Comment: Actually fred im not being nice about it. How do you feel if you dont know anything about a certain thing and then you ask someone and that someone only answers the way you do. How will you feel about it? And take note that you have explained your question to that man completely but then he answered as if you know all things and you dont need to ask him anymore? I dont know all the things about php and I've been coding about php for the past 2 days only. That's why I stated in my question to please supply a VERY UNDERSTANDABLE reply because I'm new in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set which database to use

```
<Select type="text"  style="width:220px; height: 30px;">

    <?php
    $dbname = 'databasename';

    if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')) {
        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';

    }
    mysql_select_db($dn_name);


    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();

    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tables = $row[0];
        echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
    }


    mysql_free_result($result);

    ?>


</select>
```

Would suggest you to switch from mysql_* to mysqli_*

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))` will not produce `$tables = $r['databasename'];`. And it should be `$row[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php
$DBUser = "root";
$DBPass = ""; // Empty for XAMPP Local Host
$DBName = "YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE"; // Put your Database Name Here

// MySQLi CONNECTION //
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$DBUser,$DBPass,$DBName);

// QUERY //
$sql="SHOW TABLES";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// SHOWING VALUE IN SELECT/OPTION
echo '<select>';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<option>" . $row[0] . "</option><br />";
}
echo '</select>';

// CLOSING CONNECTION //
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks...